# An urn has ten black ball numbered from 1 to 10 and ten white ball numbered from 1 to 10.

Tags: combinatorics

> An urn has ten black ball numbered from 1 to 10 and ten white ball numbered from 1
>   to 10.
>
> how many ways can we choose five balls from the urn so that the numbers on the
>   chosen balls are distinct

Ans= $\binom{10}{5} * {2^5}$

why is $2^5$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $2^5$ comes from choosing the colors of the balls.  The factor ${10 \choose 5}$ is the number of ways to choose which numbers will be represented, but you still haven't specified which ball of each number.

Comment: I got it now, but what do you mean "you still haven't specified which ball of each number.", so the answer is wrong?

Comment: The answer is right.  "you still haven't specified" is at the point you have chosen the numbers.  Then you choose the colors (in $2^5$ ways) and you are done.

Answer (score 1):

Given $10$ different numbers we can choose $5$ of them in ${10\choose 5}$ ways. Once this has been done we have $2$ choices for the color of the balls chosen, that is white or black. Since we have chosen $5$ balls there are $2^5$ ways to pick a color. Thus we can choose $5$ balls from the urn such that the numbers on the balls are distinct in ${10\choose 5}2^5$ ways.